# Grouping in Oracle Ignoring the NULL

Tags: oracle

[image]

Hi 
I have the above table of data, I would like to group them into a single row ignoring NULL values, Any help on this greatly appreciated,

Comment: Since I don't see an aggregate, why not filter the `NULL` values instead of using a group by?

Comment: Can you give a broader sample of data, along with expected results?  For example, if you have two rows for the same class ID and they each have a different `notice` value, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Hambone, added the test data over here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d7fd, Test data has 4 rows, I would want them to converge to 3 rows ignoring the NULLs

Comment: This is very helpful; thanks.  Just to be clear, what is your expected output?  In particular, when I see the last two lines, I am not sure how you would want them rendered?  Also, does this have to be done in SQL, or are you open to wrapper code that could handle the task?

Comment: Better if its done in SQL,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lag and partition can solve my requirement

```
SELECT FUND_CLASS_ID,

         NVL(SUB_NOTICE_DAYS     , LAG (SUB_NOTICE_DAYS     , 1) OVER (PARTITION BY LFC.ID ORDER BY SUB_NOTICE_DAYS       NULLS LAST)) SUB_NOTICE_DAYS     , 
         NVL(SUB_NOTICE_TYPE_OF_DAYS_ID             , LAG (SUB_NOTICE_TYPE_OF_DAYS_ID             , 1) OVER (PARTITION BY LFC.ID ORDER BY SUB_NOTICE_TYPE_OF_DAYS_ID               NULLS LAST)) SUB_NOTICE_TYPE_OF_DAYS_ID  
     FROM CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, it will work

```
   select   max(classid),
    classname,
    max(frequency),
    max(notice),
    max(typeofdays),
    max(rnotice),
    max(classpercent)
  from <table_name>
  group by classname;
```